# nonexistant memory in gdb

Tags: c, operating-system, out-of-memory, scheduler

I'm working on an OS class project with a variant of HOCA system.

I'm trying to create the interrupt handler part of the OS where I/O device interrupts are detected and handled.

(If you have no idea about HOCA, that's fine) My question is really about the internal manipulation of C.

The whole system work like this:

Main function of the OS calls an init() where all the parts are initialized.

After initializing the OS, the root process is created and the first application is schedule()'ed to the specific application. Then the application processes are created and schedule()'ed in a tree structure which rooted from the root process.

```
void schedule(){
    proc_t *front;
    front = headQueue(RQ); //return the first available process in the Ready Queue
    if (checkPointer(front)) {
        intschedule();     // load a timeslice to the OS
        LDST(&(front->p_s));  // load the state to the OS
                              // so that OS can process the application specified by p_s
                              // LDST() is system function to load a state to processor
    }
    else {
        intdeadlock();     // unlock a process from the blocked list and put in RQ
    }
}
```

Using gdb, I see everything is ok, until it processes right before if(checkPointer(front))

```
int checkPointer(void *p){
    return ((p != (void *) ENULL)&&(p != (void *)NULL));
}
```

gdb respond:

> trap: nonexistant memory address: -1 memory size: 131072 ERROR: 
>   address greater than MEMORYSIZE

what's going wrong with this?

checkPointer() is located in another file.

Your help is much appreciated.

Comment: What is the value of ENULL

Comment: NULL is set to 0 whereas ENULL is set to -1. (sorry for not clearifying that)

Comment: so that's it, GDB says the pointer is pointing to an invalid memory address (does not know about ENULL).